# Is there a difference between "entrée" and "entry"?

Tags: synonyms, word-usage

From a recent op-ed in the Washington Post (emphasis mine):

> But immigration gives Trump **entrée** to African Americans with an issue that will resonate with many and at least give him a hearing.

I looked up "entrée" in the dictionary, and as the context and definition indicated, the meaning is extremely similar to "entry" at the least.  However, I am a native speaker who has never seen "entrée" used outside of the context of eating.

Can "entry" and "entrée" be used totally interchangeably, or does one or the other have connotation or a slightly different meaning or usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An entry is  place where you enter; entrée is permission to enter.

(An entrée is also the main course of a meal.  The two words cannot be exchanged for each other.)

The sentence means that Trump's xenophobia will be his figurative ticket into the circle of attention of black voters.

Comment: An entrée is only a main course in America. In France, and non-French-speaking countries outside North America that use French for their menus, an entrée is a starter, as you would expect from its literal translation.